# Python - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' python flask

Tags: python, database, flask, web-applications, laragon

I'm trying to populate the courses selectfield in my webapp using data from the database.
this is my attempt.

this the form
`

```
class StudentForm(FlaskForm):
    idnumber = StringField('ID Number', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=9, max=9)])
    fname = StringField('First Name', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(max=50)])
    mname = StringField('Middle Name', [validators.Length(max=50)])
    lname = StringField('Last Name', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(max=50)])
    gender = SelectField('Gender', choices=gengen)
    yearlvl = SelectField('Year Level', choices= year_level)
    course = SelectField('Course', choices= models.Courses.populate())
    submit = SubmitField("Save")
```

`

```
    @classmethod
    def populate(cls):
        curs = mysql.connection.cursor()

        sql = curs.execute("SELECT COURSEID from courses")
        if sql > 0:
            result = curs.fetchall()
        return result
```

'

when I run the program i get this error

`

```
  File "C:\laragon\SISwebapp\webapp\students\forms.py", line 15, in StudentForm
    course = SelectField('Course', choices= models.Courses.populate())
  File "C:\laragon\SISwebapp\webapp\models.py", line 87, in populate
    curs = mysql.connection.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

`
I can't seem to figure out whats wrong..

edit:

This part works fine:

```
  def all(cls):
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT * from courses"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

It fetches all the data from the database table. However, it doesn't work when selecting only one column.
Please bear with me. I'm new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: What is `mysql.connection`? What connector package is in use?

Answer (score 0):

To create a cursor, use the `cursor()` method of a connection object:

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='Hello_World')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

Comment: my method works on other functions in the class. How come this one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `mysql.connection` object is `None` in that particular case. That's why it doesn't have a cursor attribute.

Generally, I recommend you to check how the connection has been established.
[Here](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask_db2.html) is a basic example for the connection and query objects.

Answer (score 0):

I also get same problem and I resolved by this `pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.26`